# show different navigation for internal and external users

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, navigation, visual-web-part, external-users

my scenario: my internal users navigation shows up a list of companies(document library) which they can use without any restrictions. But for my external users only a certain company is shared to them and they are only allowed to view that company files.now the navigation for my external users need to show those companies shared with him AND IF ONLY ONE company is shared with him,the navigation need to show the inner contents(document sets) of the document library of that company directly.(THIS WILL BE IMPLEMENTED THROUGH CSOM)

[image]

Comment: What is 'Company' is it a link / page or document library?

Comment: @SharePointer a company is a document library and it  the latter we have document sets

Comment: And you would like to ensure that external users only see the document library they have access to?

Comment: @SharePointer yes they should see the document libraries(companies) if they have more than one company is share to them. If only one company is shared to them they should see the document sets in that document library(company) in the navigation,saving them one click

Answer (score 1):

Set target audience in navigation and hide the link from the external user from document set link.

Comment: can you be more specific on the steps to take please,am still a beginner

Comment: please refer 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint will do this out of the box through security trimming.  You can create permission groups and give access as appropriate to the external users.  The Users (Internal or External) won't see the link on the navigation if they don't have access to the particular document library / page (or any other apps).

Saving them one click to reach to the document set directly instead of the document library link provided, I don't think it is possible OOTB.

You might want to consider creating a page for external users (with restricted permissions) and placing the document library or document set directly on the page.

Comment: your suggestion was the first thing i did try,but the real implementation of this is going to be done directly through csom. whenever a new company is created,the permissions are assigned by csom and the document set are also created throught csom. Is there a way to achieve that even if it is not OOTB